# jQuery animation bottom padding

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I've got another beginner question about my jQuery script. I have a script that makes the menu move to the right a little. 1st issue is that the `<a>` is somehow getting bottom padding and I don't know why and how. 2nd question is how to fill entire `<td>` with `<a>` element. I'm beginner in jQuery and searching for some ways to learn so be patient with me. Thanks for any answers a lot.

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu a').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({width: '180px'}, "slow");
    }, function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({width: '160px'}, "slow");
    });
});
```

jsFiddle demo: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tKfAL/5/)

Comment: i didn't notice the bottom padding in your fiddle and bit confused about your 2nd question

Comment: @albru13 Your tags are not showing in your question. Accept my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using a table for the menu. There is absolutely no reason for that. Use an unordered list instead, like:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

You could then style it as:

```
#menu {list-style-type: none; margin:0;padding:0;}
#menu > li {background: #8B0B04;width: 160px;padding: 7px 30px 7px 0px;}
#menu a {color: #A9A582;text-decoration: none; font: 17px bold Helvetica;width: 100%; height: 100%}
```

Regarding to your second question, i am not sure what you mean? (:

Edit:

Oh and the jquery you could just change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu > li').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({width: '180px'}, "slow");
    }, function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({width: '160px'}, "slow");
    });
});
```

And with the edit now i understand your second question. I've made a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k8vsA/

Comment: This works great, but reason for switching to table was, that I can have some space between the table rows, somehow the border attribute won't work for me, now it's amazing. Thanks for this!

Comment: Your'e welcome (: If you want space between the menu item you would just put a margin-bottom on the "li" like: #menu > li {background: #8B0B04; width: 160px; margin-bottom: 5px;}